# Fuse panel location

Tags: electrical, toyota, camry, fuse-panel

1993 Toyota Camry. I had a bad short on my electrical radiator cooling fans that caused my power windows, all dash electronics, and headlights and side marker lights to stop working. **I am trying to locate the fuses and relays for these units.**

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Owners manual should locate it/them. There may be some in passenger compartment and there may also be some under the hood.

Comment: Always found getting a workshop manual for the vehicles I own is a good investment...

Answer (score 2):

Here are the Fuse and relay locations for a 93 Camry 4cyl.

[image]

.
[image]

.
[image]

.
[image]

.
[image]

.
[image]

.
[image]

.
[image]